# add class to $(this) parent only jquery

Tags: jquery, css, parent

In Joomla I have a web page that, depending on the page, the modules on the right change, each module only has a class that distinguish them, all of them are the same. Since I cannot change this I thought that I could get the text of their heading, trim it and compare it and depending on the outcome add a class so specific css rules would apply, this works fine, but on a module I need to add the class to the .moduletable div not the h3 part how can I do this? here's my code:

```
   $('#right .moduletable h3').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text().trim();
    console.log(text);
    switch(text){
        case 'Ultimos Tips!':
            $(this).addClass('conAmor');
            break;
        case '¿Conoces los códigos QR?':
            $(this).addClass('quienesSomos');
            break;
        case 'Productos':
            $(this).addClass('productos');
            break;
        case 'carouselcavero':
            $(this, ':parent').addClass('carromod');
            break;
    }
});
```

The last case is the one that I need, it does add the class but it keeps adding it to the h3 not the parent div.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().addClass('carromod');
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
        $(this, ':parent').addClass('carromod');
```

To:

```
        $(this).parent().addClass('carromod');
```

Comment: This answer should be removed as it is already provided in the above answer.